# HDMI output on Gigabyte Brix Pro, working on some displays, not others

Tags: display, hdmi

My office has a [Gigabyte Brix Pro](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4888#ov) that my boss wants to be able to take with him occasionally to work from home on it.  The problem is that it has issues (or a monitor with it) with the HDMI output to the display (it only has HDMI output and miniDisplayPort).

Here's what has happened so far:

- Take boss's HP Pavilion 27-inch LED monitor and hook it up with his HDMI cable.  Works fine.
- Boss brings in a (can't remember...acer or samsung) monitor from home that has HDMI input, same cable.  Monitor does not display, neither of us can figure out why.  He uses the monitor with his laptop so he knows it works.
- We purchase a JVC 39" 1080p LED HDTV with HDMI inputs and a new cable.  Works fine.
- Boss takes Brix home and tries to use it with a new monitor he just purchased and the same cable we had used for the first two monitors, does not display.

I'm at a loss, I do not know why some displays will work and others will not.  I don't think it is the cable, since it worked with one display and not with another.  The Brix works fine, I did not detect any hardware issues though I may take a shot at reinstalling display drivers (?)

Edit: I'll add that Windows would not load until I switched from EFI to Legacy boot mode in the BIOS.  That's the only modification I had to make when I set the system up.  Also both monitors that have not worked properly may have been Samsung...but that still doesn't make sense to me if true.

Comment: For some video cards, it will only output to HDMI if it was (the only output) connected at boot time.

Comment: What operating system are you using? (Be as precise as possible. For example, don't say 'Windows' but 'Windows 8.1 pro, 64-bit'.)

Comment: Hi thank you for responding.  It's running Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, fully up to date.  Each time the display would not work properly the computer was restarted at least a few times with the monitor already connected.  The input setting on the display was also set to HDMI in each case, just to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: The interesting thing is, that I have an old Acer AX pc with an NVIDIA card, I connected to the monitor with HDMI and worked. No idea why isn't working with the brix pro. This week I will try a MDP/HDMI cable...